# Strange gettext behaviour with value stored in a variable

Tags: php, gettext

I have some code like the following:

```
<?php $subtitle = _('Products'); ?>
```

Later on I output the value of $subtitle

```
<h2><?php echo $subtitle; ?></h2>
```

I would have thought that it would output the translated value of Products, but instead it outputs the English value. If I change the section where I output the value to the following, it works correctly.

```
<h2><?php echo _($subtitle); ?></h2>
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I had assumed that the value in $subtitle would be the translated value, but it does not appear to be the case.

Comment: This example looks like you get the correct result when you pipe the string twice through gettext, which would indicate a mixup in the translation files and/or current locale setting (or even input charset).

Comment: I discovered what the problem was, and it was incredibly stupid. On many of the pages, the $subtitle assignment was taking place before the locale was set. I didn't notice because the code where the locale is set is in an included common header file.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what the problem was, and it was incredibly stupid. On many of the pages, the $subtitle assignment was taking place before the locale was set. I didn't notice because the code where the locale is set is in an included common header file.